# Specifically identify and display which argument in the input is not an int

Tags: java

I am developing a TCP application Java that involves a simple math operation. As part of the validation process, I want to be able to specifically identify which part of the command entered by the user is not an integer. The syntax for entering the command is as follows: `cmd x y` --> for example: `add 5 10`

**Expected Result:**
Input: `add xyz 20`
Output: `Error: “xyz” is not a number!`

**Actual Result:**
Input: `add xyz 20`
Output: `Error: not a number`
It does not specifically say which part of the input is not a number.

I used try-catch to do this validation. I am unsure how to achieve the expected result.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
String command = br.readLine();
String response = "";
int val = 0;

try 
{
    String[] arrList = command.trim().split("\\s+");
    String operator = arr[0];
    int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(arrList[1]);
    int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(arrList[2]);

    if (operator.equals("add")) 
    {
        val = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        response = "The add result is: " + String.valueOf(val);                 
    }
    else if (operator.equals("subtract")) 
    {
        val = firstNumber - secondNumber;
        response = "The subtract result is: " + String.valueOf(val);
    } 
    else if (operator.equals("multiply")) 
    {
        val = firstNumber * secondNumber;
        response = "The multiply result is: " + String.valueOf(val);
    }
    else if (operator.equals("divide")) 
    {
        if (secondNumber == 0) 
        {
            response = "Divided by zero exception";
        } 
        else 
        {
            val = firstNumber / secondNumber;
            response = "The divide result is: " + String.valueOf(val);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        response = "Invalid command '" + operator + "'";
    }
} 
catch (NumberFormatException e) 
{
    response = "Error: not a number";
}
```

Comment: Have one exception handler per call to `Integer.parseInt()`, or maintain some state representing "I am about to parse X".

Comment: @jarmod hi! thank you so much for taking the time to help. could you explain/elaborate a little more --> (or maintain some state representing "I am about to parse X".)? sorry i'm a newbie to java or programming in general!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to maintain some state indicating which parameter you are parsing, in case an error happens.

For example:

```
String parsing = "";

try 
{
    String[] arrList = command.trim().split("\\s+");
    String operator = arr[0];
    parsing = arrList[1];
    int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(parsing);
    parsing = arrList[2];
    int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(parsing);
    ...
} 
catch (NumberFormatException e) 
{
    response = "Error: \"" + parsing + "\" is not a number!";
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for ur detailed explanation and example as well! appreciate it and i understood the parsing concept better!